# Excel VBA display dialog locked in front of screen during macro

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked for this everywhere in vain.

I have a macro in one Excel file (`SplitTickets.xlsm`) that loops through 3 separate Excel files.
When `SplitTickets` is opened a dialog appears with a button to launch the macro.

Since I don't want users to mess with the excel with accidental keys or clicks while the macro is running, I would like to keep the dialog on top of all the files being opened, modified and closed, and update the label displayed when the process is over.

I tried setting it up as `modal` but since the macro needs to select sheets, cells and ranges, the dialog being `modal` blocks the rest of the macro being executed.
And turning `modal` off makes it disappear beneath the flurry of the macro's manipulations.

How can I keep this dialog on top without turning it `modal`?

Comment: I do not recommend using `.Select` if you can avoid it.  Many times `Worksheets("name").Select` `Cells(1,1).Select` `Selection.Value` can just be turned into `Worksheets("name").Cells(1,1).Value` to increase the efficiency of your code.  I may be wrong but after reading your questions that's what it sounds like you are doing.

Comment: I agree with you and that's how I handled it elsewhere, but here it's a psychological issue.
The script that would run the macro is to be run by other users and I want them to be able to see stuff happening. It's a minor detail but when I showed it to them they were impressed and liked it (they've never seen a macro run on different files and modify everything perfectly at lightspeed). Using this script implicates a business process change for them even if they will save time, so the "wow" factor was there to make the medicine go down, in a way. I know it sounds ridiculous but it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code instead.  I use it on regular basis when I don't want the user to interfere with the code run.

```
Sub Testing()

  Application.Screenupdating = False

  Your Code

  'This is very important, or it will remain disabled.
  Application.Screenupdating = true

End sub
```

This way the user is not aware of what is happening in the background.

Sandesh  :)

Comment: Thanks man it was good and worked perfectly for my initial question but in the end I figured that leaving the dialog on top is enough.
As I said in a reply to a comment in response to my post, I liked the impact the visual had on the users. They were pretty reticent to this change but now they think it's "cool" or something. I didn't have the heart to tell them it's just a macro :D

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to the start of your macro:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

This will turn off the "flurry of macro" activity you can see, so the users aren't tempted to interfere.  It will also make your macro run faster, because it no longer has to redraw the screen between each step.  Be sure to set it back to `True` at the end of the macro.

You may also want to use this option as well:

```
Application.Cursor = xlWait
```

This will turn the mouse cursor to an hourglass (or whatever "wait" cursor is set in their system) so the user knows the macro is running.  To disable the hourglass, use this:

```
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```

Beyond this, the macro should automatically prevent the user from interfering with the sheets while it is running.  However, it will keep a queue of the keystrokes made while the macro is running and enter them after the macro is done.

Comment: I also used this on top of the screenupdate and it worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a `Formname.Show` at the end of you macro to make it reappear?